How to Resolve Bad_IdentityTokenInvalid (0x80200000) Error in Python with OPC UA?
I am working on a Python application that communicates with an OPC UA server. Recently, I encountered the following error:
ServiceResult: Bad_IdentityTokenInvalid (0x80200000) "The user identity token is not valid."

I’m using the opcua Python library.[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/Jp4GTtR2.png)

Ensured the OPC UA server is configured to accept the credentials I’m using.
Consulted the opcua library documentation for guidance on setting user credentials.
What might be causing the Bad_IdentityTokenInvalid error in my scenario?
How can I resolve this issue? Are there specific settings or configurations I should check on the OPC UA server or in the opcua library?
Any help or insights on resolving this error would be greatly appreciated!
